# unable to connect through telnet in windows 7

Tags: windows, networking, windows-7, telnet

I'm trying to connect to my computer through telnet.
I've turned telnet client and server on. I've opened port 23 on my computer firewall and on my router.

But when i test it:

```
C:\>telnet 192.168.1.106
```

I've got this error:

```
Connecting To 192.168.1.106...Could not open connection to the host, on port 23: Connect failed
```

**SOLUTION**

the telnet service was disabled. enabling it solve the problem

Comment: Are you trying to telnet from the same network or from another network?

Comment: from the same computer

Comment: Why on earth are you using telnet in 2013?

Comment: As a web browser :P

Comment: because i need to connect and send command to windows servers through java. and since there isnt ssh on windows, only telnet - i use telnet..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the services console and verify that the Telnet service is running.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a telnet clients user group on your local machine? Run lusrmgr.msc and check. If so, add your user account to it. Have you tried with the windows firewall completely turned off? I haven't touched the telnet server in ages, but do you have a configuration option to either bind it to your IP address or 127.0.0.1 since it is your local machine?

It's also very possible that you can't telnet to the same machine you are on due to how it loopbacks. Try doing this from another machine on your network.